# C# как в List добавить произвольное поле или объединить

Tags: c#, entity-framework, list, soap

Есть конструкция классов

```
  importMeteringDeviceDataRequest = new importMeteringDeviceDataRequest
  {
    FIASHouseGuid = res.FIASHouseGUID.ToString(),
    MeteringDevice = new importMeteringDeviceDataRequestMeteringDevice[]
    {
      new importMeteringDeviceDataRequestMeteringDevice
      {
        TransportGUID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
        Item = new MeteringDeviceFullInformationType
        {
          BasicChatacteristicts = new MeteringDeviceBasicCharacteristicsType
          {
            MeteringDeviceNumber = res.MeteringDeviceNumber,
            MeteringDeviceModel = res.MeteringDeviceModel,
            MeteringDeviceStamp = res.MeteringDeviceStamp, .... И.Т.Д
```

Я этот `importMeteringDeviceDataRequestMeteringDevice[]` массив собираю, но мне нужно еще передавать вот этот параметр  `FIASHouseGuid = res.FIASHouseGUID.ToString()`,
 Он идет вне массива, и как правильно это сделать, не пойму. Изначально задача -  передать эти параметры в soap запросе, сгенерировал прокси классы и предаю в них значения, если делать по одной записи - то все ок, но можно передавать одновременно по 100 записей. Только вот `FIASHouseGuid` из массива выбивается и как его передать не понятно. Таблица одна там все записи храниться.

Полный текст

```
public async void ImportMeteringDataAdd()
{
        inserted = 0;
   var importIPU = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            IsBusy = true;
            soapEntities db = new soapEntities();
            AuthClass auth = new Data.AuthClass();
            var service = new HouseManagementPortsTypeAsyncClient();
            service.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = auth.LoginEais;
            service.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = auth.PasswordEais;               
            List<string> accGuid = new List<string>();                             
            var r = db.eias_MeteringDevice.Include("eias_MeteringDevice_Account").Select(c => c).ToList();
            count = r.Count;

            foreach (var res in r)
            {
                foreach (var item in res.eias_MeteringDevice_Account)
                {
                    accGuid.Add(item.AccountGUID.ToString());
                }


            try
            {
                    var request = new importMeteringDeviceDataRequest1
                    {

                        RequestHeader = new RequestHeader
                        {

                            Date = DateTime.Now,
                            MessageGUID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                            ItemElementName = ItemChoiceType.orgPPAGUID,
                            Item = auth.GuidORG,
                            IsOperatorSignature = true,
                            IsOperatorSignatureSpecified = true


                        },
                        importMeteringDeviceDataRequest = new importMeteringDeviceDataRequest
                        {

                            FIASHouseGuid = res.FIASHouseGUID.ToString(),

                        MeteringDevice = new importMeteringDeviceDataRequestMeteringDevice[]
                                 {

                                     new importMeteringDeviceDataRequestMeteringDevice
                                     {
                                        TransportGUID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),

                                        Item = new MeteringDeviceFullInformationType

                                 {

                                   BasicChatacteristicts = new MeteringDeviceBasicCharacteristicsType
                                    {
                                         MeteringDeviceNumber = res.MeteringDeviceNumber,
                                         MeteringDeviceModel = res.MeteringDeviceModel,
                                         MeteringDeviceStamp = res.MeteringDeviceStamp,
                                        CommissioningDate = res.CommissioningDate.Value,
                                        CommissioningDateSpecified = true ,
                                     //   VerificationInterval  = new nsiRef { }
                                      InstallationDate = res.InstallationDate.Value,
                                      RemoteMeteringMode = res.RemoteMeteringMode.Value,
                                     TemperatureSensor = res.TemperatureSensor.Value,
                                      PressureSensor =res.PressureSensor.Value ,
                                      Item = new  MeteringDeviceBasicCharacteristicsTypeResidentialPremiseDevice
                                          {

                                              AccountGUID = accGuid.ToArray() ,
                                              PremiseGUID = res.Residential_PremiseGUID.ToString().ToLower()

                                         },



                                 //   // FirstVerificationDate = res.LastVerificationDate.Value


                                     },
                                            Item = true,
                                            Items = new MunicipalResourceNotElectricType[]
                                            {
                                                new MunicipalResourceNotElectricType
                                                {
                                                    MeteringValue = res.MeteringValueT1.Value,//Первоначальное значение
                                                    MunicipalResource = new Gis.Infrastructure.HouseManagementService.nsiRef
                                                    {
                                                        Code = res.MunicipalResource,
                                                        GUID = res.MunicipalResourceGUID.ToString().ToLower()
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }




                                 }
                                 //        }
                                     }
                         }
                    }

                };
                var result = service.importMeteringDeviceData(request);


                GuidService gs = new GuidService
                {
                    GuidID = new Guid(result.AckRequest.Ack.MessageGUID),
                    DateGuid = DateTime.Now,
                    MetodId = 14,
                    Descript = result.AckRequest.Ack.RequesterMessageGUID,
                    State = 1
                };
                db.GuidServices.Add(gs);
                db.SaveChanges();


                for (int i = 0; i < accGuid.Count; i++)
                {


                    ImportMeteringDevice md = new Data.ImportMeteringDevice
                    {
                        GuidQ = new Guid(result.AckRequest.Ack.MessageGUID),
                        AccountGUID = new Guid(accGuid[i].ToString()),
                        //   MetKey = res.met_key,
                        State = 1
                    };
                    db.ImportMeteringDevices.Add(md);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }

                inserted++;
                updateProgress(inserted);

            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(e.Message.ToString());
                BrushSend = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Red;
                    inserted++;
                    updateProgress(inserted);
                }

            accGuid.Clear();
             }
            BrushSend = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.LimeGreen;

        });

        await importIPU;
        IsBusy = false;
}
```

Comment: Такие вложенные матрешки создания новых объектов надо разбивать на вызовы отдельных методов, иначе ваш код выглядит как жуткая запутанная лапша, ее и читать тяжело и понять еще труднее. А по сути вопроса не совсем понятна логика: "...но мне нужно еще передавать вот этот параметр FIASHouseGuid = res.FIASHouseGUID.ToString(),...". Куда передавать? Поясните, а лучше покажите код.

Comment: Покажите как разбить на вызовы я новичок

Answer (score 0):

Действовать нужно примерно в таком духе:

```
public async void ImportMeteringDataAdd()
    {
        IsBusy = true;

        try
        {
            bool resultImport = await ImportIPU();
            if (resultImport)
            {
                BrushSend = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.LimeGreen;
                IsBusy = false;
            }
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(e.Message.ToString());
            BrushSend = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Red;
            inserted++;
            updateProgress(inserted);
        }

    }

    private async Task<bool> ImportIPU()
    {
        AuthClass auth = new Data.AuthClass();
        var service = await GetService(auth);

        soapEntities db = new soapEntities();
        var ress = db.eias_MeteringDevice
                        .Include("eias_MeteringDevice_Account")
                        .Select(c => c)
                        .ToList();
        count = ress.Count;

        inserted = 0;
        List<string> accGuid;
        foreach (var res in ress)
        {
            accGuid = await GetListAccountGUID(res);

            var request = await GetMeteringDeviceDataRequest(auth, res, accGuid);
            var result = service.importMeteringDeviceData(request);

            SaveGuidService(result, db);
            SaveImportMeteringDevice(result, db, accGuid.Count);

            inserted++;
            updateProgress(inserted);
        }

        return true;
    }

    //Вместо object нужно подставить тип res
    private Task<List<string>> GetListAccountGUID(object res)
    {
        var result = new List<string>();

        foreach (var item in res.eias_MeteringDevice_Account())
        {
            result.Add(item.AccountGUID.ToString());
        }

        return Task.FromResult(result);
    }

    //Вместо object нужно подставить тип service
    private Task<object> GetService(AuthClass auth)
    {
        var service = new HouseManagementPortsTypeAsyncClient();
        service.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = auth.LoginEais;
        service.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = auth.PasswordEais;

        return Task.FromResult(service);
    }

    //Вместо object нужно подставить тип res
    private Task<importMeteringDeviceDataRequest1> GetMeteringDeviceDataRequest(AuthClass auth, object res, List<string> accGuid)
    {
        var result = new importMeteringDeviceDataRequest1
        {
            RequestHeader = GetRequestHeader(auth),
            importMeteringDeviceDataRequest = GetCoreRequest(res, accGuid)
        };

        return Task.FromResult(result);
    }

    private RequestHeader GetRequestHeader(AuthClass auth)
    {
        var result = new RequestHeader
        {

            Date = DateTime.Now,
            MessageGUID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            ItemElementName = ItemChoiceType.orgPPAGUID,
            Item = auth.GuidORG,
            IsOperatorSignature = true,
            IsOperatorSignatureSpecified = true


        };

        return result;
    }

    //Вместо object нужно подставить тип res
    private importMeteringDeviceDataRequest GetCoreRequest(object res, List<string> accGuid)
    {
        var result = new importMeteringDeviceDataRequest
        {
            FIASHouseGuid = res.FIASHouseGUID.ToString(),
            MeteringDevice = GetArrayMeteringDevice(res, accGuid)
        };

        return result;
    }

    private importMeteringDeviceDataRequestMeteringDevice[] GetArrayMeteringDevice(object res, List<string> accGuid)
    {
        var result = new importMeteringDeviceDataRequestMeteringDevice[]
        {
            //Принцип надеюсь вам понятен
            //Далее я думаю, вы справитесь самостоятельно:)

        };

        return result;
    }

    //Вместо object нужно подставить тип result
    private void SaveGuidService(object result, soapEntities db)
    {
        GuidService gs = new GuidService
        {
            GuidID = new Guid(result.AckRequest.Ack.MessageGUID),
            DateGuid = DateTime.Now,
            MetodId = 14,
            Descript = result.AckRequest.Ack.RequesterMessageGUID,
            State = 1
        };
        db.GuidServices.Add(gs);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    //Вместо object нужно подставить тип
    private void SaveImportMeteringDevice(object result, soapEntities db, int count)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            ImportMeteringDevice md = new Data.ImportMeteringDevice
            {
                GuidQ = new Guid(result.AckRequest.Ack.MessageGUID),
                AccountGUID = new Guid(accGuid[i].ToString()),
                //   MetKey = res.met_key,
                State = 1
            };
            db.ImportMeteringDevices.Add(md);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```